# File permissions not changed during moved from one folder to another one

Tags: powershell

In D drive :

FolderA contents a PDF file and a user Mr John have full rights on this folder and files.
We need this file auto moved to FolderB where Mr John is restrict to edit the file.

I wrote the power shell scrip as :
Move-Item -Path D:\FolderA*.PDF* -Destination D:\FolderB\ -Force

The file is auto moved to FolderB but the permissions still appearing of Folder A ! means Mr John is restricted in FolderB but after moving the file he can edit it.

This is the problem and i want that after moved file from FolderA to FolderB then the permission should be applied of Folder B only means Mr John can not edit the file.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with inheritance last year where I moved many big files from one drive to another.

Solved it by applying the ACL again for each file separately.

```
$file | Get-Acl | Set-Acl
```

The answer to "Why" is still open...
Guess it has something to do with the file handle and lock.
Had also some issues to access a file after moving it on that server (between drives) while the PS console window was still open. After closing, the file was accessible.

Hope that's still a reasonable way for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders): *By default, an object inherits permissions from its parent object, either at the time of creation or when it is copied or moved to its parent folder. The only exception to this rule occurs when you **move** an object to a different folder **on the same volume**. In this case, the original permissions are retained.*

Instead of using `Move-Item` from FolderA, do a `Copy-Item` to FolderB and when done remove the original file from FolderA

Comment: but we dont want to keep the file in FolderA as its not required.

Comment: @MOHDSHEZAN That is why i ended my answer with _"when done remove the original file from FolderA"_ (---> use `Remove-Item`)